# Update column in the record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update one 2 tables column data in about 10 records and want to make sure that by doing that i dont corrupt the database. As far as I can see column i want to update is not primary nor foreign key.   Any advice?

Comment: Missing information about what RDBMS you are using. Table definitions. Example data and desired results.

Comment: Ms sql. Well can you tell me what do i have to ensure in order to do this properly. What to watch for?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 0):

You can get constraint information (primary keys, foreign keys, checks, Uniques, ...)  with the below query,

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME=‘Your_Table_Name’
```